# How Do type random text in imacros?

Tags: text, random, web-scraping, imacros

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:frmSendSms ATTR=ID:Message_ CONTENT=Ranndom text
```

How to type random text in this `iMacros Command`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:frmSendSms ATTR=ID:Message_ CONTENT={{random_text}}"



var random_text="Some random text";

iimSet("random_text",random_text)
iimPlay(macro)
```

This could do the trick.